# How can I use a string array as key in hash map?

Tags: java, arrays, string, hashmap

I've made an String array out of a .txt and now want to make a HashMap with this string as key. But I don't want to have the String as one key to one value, I want to have each Information as a new key for the HashMap.

```
private static String[] readAndConvertInputFile() {
String str = StdIn.readAll();
String conv = str.replaceAll("\'s", "").replaceAll("[;,?.:*/\\-_()\"\'\n]", " ").replaceAll(" {2,}", " ").toLowerCase();
return conv.split(" ");  }
```

So the information in the string is like ("word", "thing", "etc.", "pp.", "thing").

My value should be the frequency of the word in the text. So for example     key: "word" value: 1, key: "thing" value: 2  and so on... I'm clueless and would be grateful if someone could help me, at least with the key. :)

Comment: Are you looking for [MultiMap](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)?

Comment: @StackFlowed Might want to toss a closing bracket there ;)

Comment: Please provide an example of what you want in the map to map to what. If you want to do a count of each individual word, then please specify it as such.

Comment: Did you try going through the array elements in a loop, and incrementing the map values for each word you see? Did it not work? What was the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Map` while using the `String` value at each `array` index as the key, and an `Integer` as the value to keep track of how many times a word appeared.

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Then when you want to increment, you can check if the `Map` already contains the key, if it does, increase it by 1, otherwise, set it to 1.

```
if (occurences.containsKey(word)) {
    occurences.put(word, occurences.get(word) + 1);
} else {
    occurences.put(word, 1);
}
```

So, while you are looping over your string array, convert the `String` to lower case (if you want to ignore case for word occurrences), and increment the map using the `if` statement above.

```
for (String word : words) {
    word = word.toLowerCase(); // remove if you want case sensitivity
    if (occurences.containsKey(word)) {
        occurences.put(word, occurences.get(word) + 1);
    } else {
        occurences.put(word, 1);
    }
}
```

A full example is shown below. I converted to words to lowercase to ignore case when using the key in the map, if you want to keep case, remove the line where I convert it to lowercase.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "This this the has dog cat fish the cat horse";
    String[] words = s.split(" ");
    Map<String, Integer> occurences = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (String word : words) {
        word = word.toLowerCase(); // remove if you want case sensitivity
        if (occurences.containsKey(word)) {
            occurences.put(word, occurences.get(word) + 1);
        } else {
            occurences.put(word, 1);
        }
    }

    for(Entry<String,Integer> en : occurences.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("Word \"" + en.getKey() + "\" appeared " + en.getValue() + " times.");
    }

}
```

Which will give me output:

```
Word "cat" appeared 2 times.
Word "fish" appeared 1 times.
Word "horse" appeared 1 times.
Word "the" appeared 2 times.
Word "dog" appeared 1 times.
Word "this" appeared 2 times.
Word "has" appeared 1 times.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you *can* use an array (regardless of element type) as a `HashMap` key.

No, *shouldn't* do so.  The behavior is unlikely to be what you want (in general).

In your particular case, I don't see why you even propose using an array as a key in the first place.  You seem to want `String`s drawn from among your array elements as keys.

You could construct a word frequency table like so:

```
Map<String, Integer> computeFrequencies(String[] words) {
    Map<String, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (String word: words) {
        Integer wordFrequency = frequencies.get(word);

        frequencies.put(word,
                (wordFrequency == null) ? 1 : (wordFrequency + 1));
    }

    return frequencies;
}
```

Comment: If you wanted to be really tricky, seeing as we're using a ternary operator, you can do `frequencies.put(word, (frequencies.containsKey(word)) ? frequencies.get(word) + 1 : 1);` inside the for loop. Kills readability, of course.

Comment: @Compass, yes, you could, but then you would be doing three lookups in the map instead of two for the second and subsequent appearances of each word (one each for `containsKey()`, `get()`, and `put()`).  As a general rule, `containsKey()` is wasteful if you're going to follow up with a `get()`.

Comment: Unless, that is, you have to worry about the key actually being mapped to `null`.

Comment: Trickiness is not the objective, by the way.  I find this particular code clearer than its `if` / `else` analogue.

Comment: I know. :P I just enjoy finding ways to really make Java look weird.

Answer (score 0):

In java 8 using stream

```
String[] array=new String[]{"a","b","c","a"};
Map<String,Integer> map1=Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.toMap(x->x,x->1,(key,value)->value+1));
```